# Typescript removing other properties from object with "as"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to send an object via JSON, which implements an interface, but also has some other properties that I don't want to send. How can I "remove" everything else so I have a pure object with only the interface properties?

Example:

```
interface IBlock{
  x:number;
  y:number;
}

class Block implements IBlock{
  public z:number;
}
...
send(JSON.stringify(new Block() as IBlock));

responseIWant = "{x:0,y:0}";
responseIGet = "{x:0,y:0,z:0}";
```

Comment: No, `as` is just a hint for the type checker, it doesn't do anything at runtime.

Comment: Oh, and how can I remove everything else, without writing a copy constructor?

Comment: Not at all, afaik. You can also try the [replacer callback of `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), but you'd need to reificate the interface somehow for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `interfaces` and casting using `as` are compile time constructs that don't do anything at runtime when the code is actually executed.

You could use the `pick` method from `lodash`:

```
const subset = _.pick(obj, ['x', 'y'])
```

Or if you don't want to bring in a library you could do this with destructuring:

```
const subset = (({ x, y }) => ({ x, y }))(obj);
```

Another more advanced technique would be using actual classes with `reflect-metadata` and decorators to be able to make better decisions about the content of your code at runtime.